# Where can I use 'GET_LOCK'?

Tags: mysql

Who can share practical examples of the use of the `GET_LOCK` function?

Example function:

```
mysql> SELECT GET_LOCK('b',10);
+------------------+
| GET_LOCK('b',10) |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT IS_FREE_LOCK('b');
+-------------------+
| IS_FREE_LOCK('b') |
+-------------------+
|                 0 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('b');
+-------------------+
| RELEASE_LOCK('b') |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT IS_FREE_LOCK('b');
+-------------------+
| IS_FREE_LOCK('b') |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you say what is practical? It seems like a relative term.

Comment: A practical example of use is: Dynamic cursors. Here's an article about it, including code and explanation. [MariaDB / MySQL: Dynamic SQL Cursors for](http://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/mariadbmysql-cursors-for-dynamic-sql/).

Answer (score 0):

Resource locking, eg execute only once in some distributed systems.

For example here's tiny app which uses it: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karnauskas/f6dd0a8608c9a335e17890d3755d5d5a/raw/6bdfa36d93ac1f171ccf0ba5152aa8765c052a96/mysql_lock.go

Comment: This page is not found (404 error) as at May 24, 2020.

Comment: I think I moved it to this gist https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karnauskas/f6dd0a8608c9a335e17890d3755d5d5a/raw/6bdfa36d93ac1f171ccf0ba5152aa8765c052a96/mysql_lock.go

Comment: thanx. I do not think get_lock will work for me. I am going to reseach mysql row locks

Answer (score 0):

Implementing **distributed locking**, as described in [this article](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/26/how-to-coordinate-distributed-work-with-mysqls-get_lock/).

Essentially, if you need to restrict access to some resource X for programs P1, P2, P3, ..., then each program needs to call `GET_LOCK("some-agreed-on-string")` and only the one which got `1` in response proceeds.